# VBA texttocolumns ignores one column

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I have data that was previously improted into Excel and want to have that data automatically put into the proper format.

Right now my dates look like this: 28122012  which should be 28.12.2012
My code, which I've put together with some sources I've found online, works well except for one snag... it ignores column V:

```
   Dim rngS As Range
    For Each rngS In .Range("F:F,U:W").Columns
        rngS.TextToColumns Destination:=rngS.Cells(1, 1),  _ 
DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 4)
    Next
```

I'm not certain why it does this. I've experimented by writing out each column, but no go. Column V remains as it is, while everything around it gets properly formatted.

Any ideas why this could be?

Thanks!

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. If you check the cell format in the V column, is it different from the other columns before the operation?

Comment: Hi Olle. It seems that the specific date that is in that column has a 0 chopped off. It's 1122012... that doesn't seem to take. In fact, looking through, i've noticed that it also happens in the other columns that do convert. There are dates there which remain in the old format. How do you get excel to convert it? Any idea? Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the field it pastes to is treating the value as numerical.

The only real remedy is to set the type to Text for that and other columns that might have such a date value. Then 01122012 will not lose its starting zero.

Alternatively you could let your follow up code or formula anticipate the missing zeroes and work back to date values using `LEFT()`, `RIGHT()` and like functions.